# Recommended Personal Web Servers

Tags: web-hosting, webserver

I'm looking for a Personal web server to host very light traffic meant for home use only.

What is your take on personal web servers that meet some or most of the criteria below?

- Free/Open source
- Runs on Windows and possibly Linux (Ubuntu)
- Very light on resources
- No installation required or standalone file
- Admin console - GUI or Web based
- Supports multiple hosts/port mappings

I have tried Abyss who's standard edition is free but limited to one host only.
I've seen lite speed, haven't tried though
XAAMP is another one I'm considering...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using several of them, I think Abyss suits the best to my needs. This has many features out of the box is very light. Thanks everyone for their inputs.

Answer (score 6):

Apache is not the lightest, but it still doesn't use that many resources.  It is free, and is kind of the standard of webservers.  It would be my recommendation.

Comment: its feature rich and powerful, close to IIS or even beats it maybe, but as u said, its not light and i don't need something as heavy as that. besides the fact that it uses java and i don't use JRE or anything java at all.

Comment: Apache does not require Java.  Two popular lighter ones are nigix and lightpd, I still recommend Apache.  You can compile it and configure it to be pretty light.  Can use the threaded model, configure it to have less threads etc...

Comment: both nginx and lightpd lack an admin gui. i need something quick n easy like Abyss offers. i'd give apache a try at home.

Comment: Apache is widely used and widely supported, it's probably one of the easier ones to use (especially for light use) because of this.

Comment: @Mrchief: You don't need a GUI for Apache...there's one conf-file, and that's it.

Comment: @Mrchief: Webmin offers an admin GUI for Apache.  I'm not sure if it works for nginx or lighttpd

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised not to see Lighttpd.

http://www.lighttpd.net/

It isn't GUI based but it sure is light on resources and powerful.

Answer (score 1):

I've used XAMPP a number of times for development systems and/or small deployments.  It's a good solution if you want a self-contained Apache/PHP/MySQL system.  It will allow you to have multiple hosts as well since it uses Apache.  And, if any of your personal stuff requires a database, it's part of the package, so nothing extra to hunt for.

Comment: installer size is in mega bytes!! don't want something that fat.

Comment: What's the big deal about the size of the installer?  Downloading it by dial up?

Answer (score 1):

I saw that Cherokee was not listed yet, it is one amazingly fast and stable server, runs on Linux and Windows.

[http://www.cherokee-project.com](http://www.cherokee-project.com/)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows platforms, Baby Web Server could be a good alternative:

http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_web_server.html

Answer (score 0):

not open source, but free for a 'standard' version.  http://litespeedtech.com/litespeed-web-server-editions.html  very good, easy to setup and just works.

Answer (score 0):

[HFS File server](http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/) is a standalone file.  Its awesome and totally free.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your OS, and whether you want to host static or dynamic pages. i ran [xitami](http://www.xitami.com/) for years as my personal server mostly for static pages, but i ran a perl based forum too - no install required, single config file. Not tried multiple host and ports, but considering how simple it is to get up and running (download a zip file,unzip, config, fire it up) its worth a shot

Answer (score 0):

I personally would recommend Lighttpd. It runs with an extremely low overhead and short of a GUI-based config, has one of the neatest and easiest to understand configuration file(s).